Autosys Command Job is not triggering Teradata BTEQ script
I have autosys job with below JIL configuration
insert_job: APP.C
command : /NAS_MOUNT/run_bteq.ksh FOLDERNAME SCRIPTNAME.btq
machine : serverA.com
owner : John
profile: /NAS_MOUNT/.John_profile

If I run the job it's not able to execute BTEQ part, when I tried to run manually with Owner permissions and source John profile then I'm able to execute BTEQ scripts without no issues.
cat /NAS_MOUNT/run_bteq.ksh
BTEQ_SCRIPT='/NAS_MOUNT/SCRIPTNAME.btq.tmp'
cat /NAS_MOUNT/prebteq.ksh > $BTEQ_SCRIPT
cat SCRIPTNAME.btq >> $BTEQ_SCRIPT
cat /NAS_MOUNT/postbteq.ksh >> $BTEQ_SCRIPT
$BTEQ_SCRIPT
RC=$?
exit $RC

Below are the contents of tmp BTEQ_SCRIPT
bteq<<EOF
.SET WIDTH 5000
.logon a/username,PWD
select database,user ;
.logoff
.quit
EOF

exit $?

Tried to run from other server it was working well, but ServerA is alone problem here
